# Prove that for all integers $a$ and $b$, if $a\mid b$ then $a^2\mid 3b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Hello I'm having trouble finding a proof for this problem. I have the following proof so far....

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are particularly chosen integers such that $a\mid b$.
>
> By definition of divisibility $b= a\cdot k$ for some integer $k$.
>
> Then,
>
> $a^2 \mid  3b^2$
>
> $a^2 \cdot k = 3b^2$

Where should I go after this step? Is this correct?

> Let $t  = a^2 \cdot k$ because the product of integers are integers.
>
> Therefore
>
> $t \mid 3b^2$

Comment: Since $b=ak$, we have $3b^2=3(ak)^2=a^2(3k^2) \ldots$

Comment: I can see how  _3b² = 3(ak)²_  but cant see how that is equivalent to _a²(3k²)_ . Could you explain a bit? And what would be the correct category to ask this question?

Comment: Maybe the answers posted here can help you: [Show that for all integers $a$ and $b$ if $a\mid b$ then $a^2\mid b^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/684351)

Comment: @Jlee As Francesco Polizzi has explained above, just square both sides of $b=ak$ and rearrange to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: "I can see how 3b² = 3(ak)² but cant see how that is equivalent to a²(3k²) "  That's just rewriting.  Commutativity and associativtiy.  $3(ak)^2 = 2\times a\times k\times a\times k = a\times a\times 3\times k\times k = a^2(3k^2)$.  This was not meant to be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

You have things backward.  Your first sentence is right, that $b=ak$.  But then you leap to the very end and state that "Then $a^2 \mid 3b^2.$"  But that's your conclusion.  It should be the last sentence of your proof.

You need to start with $b=ak$ and work your way to $3b^2 = a^2n$ (for some integer $n$) and then you can conclude that  $a^2 \mid 3b^2.$

You might write: Well,  $b=ak$, so $b^2 = a^2k^2$, so $3b^2 = 3a^2k^2 = a^2(3k^2).$  Since $3k^2$ is an integer,$\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

It's even easier than that. if $a \mid b$, then perforce $a^2 \mid b^2$ and hence $a^2 \mid nb^2$ for all integers $n$, including $3$.